# Read and compare two large Files

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to read and compare all the lines of both files, I explain, I would like to find for each password hasher (from my test.txt file) the hashes that are the same (from the password.txt file). The problem is that it should be fast enough (I would say max 45 min for 10M for password.txt and 1M for test.txt).

I have for the moment this code

```java
private static void bufferedReaderFilePasswordFirst() {
    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\basil\\OneDrive - Haute Ecole Bruxelles Brabant (HE2B)\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\sha256\\passwords.txt");
    Path pathUser = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\basil\\OneDrive - Haute Ecole Bruxelles Brabant (HE2B)\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\sha256\\test.txt");
    int nbOfLine = 0;
    StringBuffer oui = new StringBuffer();

    try (BufferedReader readerPasswordGenerate = Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));) {

        String currentLineUser = null;
        String currentLinePassword = null;

        long start = System.nanoTime();

        while (((currentLinePassword = readerPasswordGenerate.readLine()) != null)) {
            BufferedReader readerPasswordUser = Files.newBufferedReader(pathUser, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            while ((currentLineUser = readerPasswordUser.readLine()) != null) {
                String firstWord = currentLinePassword.substring(0, currentLinePassword.indexOf(":"));
                if ((firstWord.charAt(0) == currentLineUser.charAt(0)) 
                    && (firstWord.charAt(14) == currentLineUser.charAt(14)) 
                    && (firstWord.charAt(31) == currentLineUser.charAt(31)) 
                    && (firstWord.charAt(63) == currentLineUser.charAt(63))
                ) {
                    if (firstWord.equals(currentLineUser)) {
                        String secondWord = currentLinePassword.substring(currentLinePassword.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);

                        oui.append(secondWord).append(System.lineSeparator());
                    }
                }
            }
            if (nbOfLine % 300 == 0) {
                System.out.println("We are at the " + nbOfLine);
                final long consumed = System.nanoTime() - start;
                final long totConsumed = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(consumed);
                final double tot = (double) totConsumed;
                System.out.printf("Not done. Took %s seconds", (tot / 1000));
                System.out.println(oui + " oui");
            }
            nbOfLine++;
        }
        System.out.println(oui);
        final long consumed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        final long totConsumed = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(consumed);
        final double tot = (double) totConsumed;
        System.out.printf("Done. Took %s seconds", (tot / 1000));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); //handle an exception here
    }
}
```

In this code, I just compare for each element in my `test.txt` if the corresponding element in the password hash is same.

The `password.txt` contains for all elements: `hash:password`
and `test.txt` contains only: `hash`

Thanks

Comment: You should profile the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In this code, I just compare for each element in my test.txt if the corresponding element in the password hash is same.

If you are familiar with Big-O notation, you might recognize that this means your algorithm runs in O(n^2) time. In your specific case, for each of the 1,000,000 lines in test.txt you are doing 10,000,000 comparisons for a total of 10,000,000,000,000 total comparisons. To achieve your goal of running it within 45 minutes you would need to do 3.7 *billion* comparisons per second. For comparison, the i7 in my laptop runs at a max of 3.9GHz (billion cycles per second) and it will take much more than a single cpu cycle to execute one of these comparisons.

You can reduce the time complexity down to O(n) by first reading the password.txt into a HashMap (10,000,000 operations). From there, any individual check from test.txt only takes a single operation (1,000,000 total), resulting in 11,000,000 operations total. That means you only have to do ~4,000 operations a second (a 99.99989% reduction) to finish in 45 minutes which is much more doable.

Here's some pseudo-code to illustrate what that could look like:

```
// I like Scanner over BufferedReader for reading files. Use whatever you like.
Scanner readPassword = new Scanner(new File("password.txt"));

// Load all password/hash pairings from password.txt into a HashMap for quick lookups
HashMap<String, List> passwords = new HashMap<>();
while (readPassword.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = readPassword.nextLine();
  String[] lineParts = line.split(":");
  String hash = lineParts[0];  
  String password = lineParts[1];
  
  // If we haven't seen the hash before, create a new list to store its associated passwords
  if (passwords.get(hash) == null) {
    passwords.put(hash, new LinkedList<>());
  }

  // Add the password to the list of all passwords that have this hash
  passwords.get(hash).add(password);  
}

// Perform all the lookups from test.txt
Scanner readTest = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
while (readTest.hasNextLine()) {
  String testHash = readTest.nextLine();
  List matchingPasswords = passwords.get(testHash);
  // Now do whatever you want with the list of associated passwords...
}
```

**Side Notes:**

- Looking at your code, it look like you have a few extra requirements (e.g. timing) that I didn't consider in this code snippet. I trust you can figure out how to integrate those additional requirements.
- Some of the more academic people on here might take issue with a few parts of my Big-O description/analysis. I'm sure their comments on this post will expound that topic in greater detail if that interests you.